# Why does my code return 'None' along with the correct output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program that takes 4 number inputs and passes them to a user defined function. the first value becomes the second in the list, and the 4th value becomes the third in the list. The program is supposed to output the inputs as numbers with spaces in between them.

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2, user_val3, user_val4):
    newList = [user_val2, user_val1, user_val4, user_val3]
    return print(f'{newList[0]} {newList[1]} {newList[2]} {newList[3]}')

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    val1 = int(input())
    val2 = int(input())
    val3 = int(input())
    val4 = int(input())
    print(swap_values(val1, val2, val3, val4))
```

While I do get the correct answer outputted for the input "8, 3, 4, 2", I also get 'None' right bellow it like so

```
3 8 2 4
None
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Because your function has the side-effect of printing something to the terminal (due to `print`), and it's returning the result of that `print` (which is always `None`), which you then `print` when you invoke the function. Have your function return the string, rather than the result of printing the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the function **swap_values** is first printing the value and returning the print function which is **None**
This can be fixed by using this code:

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2, user_val3, user_val4):
newList = [user_val2, user_val1, user_val4, user_val3]
return f'{newList[0]} {newList[1]} {newList[2]} {newList[3]}'
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    val1 = int(input("val1"))
    val2 = int(input("val2"))
    val3 = int(input("val3"))
    val4 = int(input("val4"))
    print(swap_values(val1, val2, val3, val4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `print` statements.

This line

```python
    return print(f'{newList[0]} {newList[1]} {newList[2]} {newList[3]}')
```

prints the four numbers, and then returns the return value of the print operation. But print doesn't have a return value in Python, so it's "None". Then this line

```python
    print(swap_values(val1, val2, val3, val4))
```

prints that return value.

You could change `swap_values()` to simply return a string, and then have the caller print it out. Or you could print the values inside `swap_values()`, and just call that function without another print statement around the call. Just don't do both.

Answer (score 0):

You print the return value from *print()* which is None.

Rather than print within the swap_values function, return the swapped values then print. For example:

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2, user_val3, user_val4):
    return user_val2, user_val1, user_val4, user_val3

print(*swap_values(1,2,3,4))
```

**Output:**

```
2 1 4 3
```